# Convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have searched SO and other sites for quite some time so I do apologize if this is a duplicate that I missed.

Given the example string Thu 09/22 15:17:46 PM - PHONE, where it comes from a table with a varchar2 datatype, I need to convert the 15:17:46 PM into 3:17PM so the resultant string is Thu 09/22 3:17PM - Phone.

The query that I'm using to retrieve the data is (part of a much larger query):

```
( SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ( notetext, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'Dy MM/DD') || ' ' || TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE (notetext, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh24:mi:ss AM') || ' - ' || notetype
              FROM
                a pnx
              WHERE
                pnx.notetype IN ('FAX', 'PHONE')
              AND pnx.episode = ep.episodenbr
            ) END)      AS RFIINDICATOR
```

Where notetext is the part that has the data Thu 09/22 15:17:46 PM and notetype has the data PHONE.  Both are varchar2 datatypes.

I have tried to call the extract function to pull out the time portion, do a

```
to_char (RFIINDICATOR, 'HH12:MI:SS PM')
```

All yielding an invalid number error or some other Oracle error.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (only one of the many ways to skin this cat):

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select 'Thu 09/22 15:17:46 PM - PHONE' from dual union all
       select 'Thu 09/22 9:17:46 AM - PHONE'  from dual
     ),
     fragments ( str, dt, other ) as (
       select str, substr(str, 1, instr(str, ' ', 1, 3) - 1),
              substr(str, instr(str, ' ', 1, 4))
       from inputs
     )
select str, to_char(to_date(dt, 'Dy mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Dy mm/dd hh:mi:ssAM') || 
                                                                      other as new_str
from   fragments
;

STR                           NEW_STR
----------------------------- ------------------------------
Thu 09/22 15:17:46 PM - PHONE Thu 09/22 03:17:46PM - PHONE
Thu 09/22 9:17:46 AM - PHONE  Thu 09/22 09:17:46AM - PHONE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Trying to add your logic to the existing huge query now.